# SQL condition from alias

Tags: sql, mariadb

This is how my SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (
        10 * MATCH(products.parameters) AGAINST('intel core i5') + 
        5 * MATCH(products.name) AGAINST('intel core i5') + 
        MATCH(products.description) AGAINST('intel core i5')
    ) AS percentage 
FROM products 
WHERE 
    (
        MATCH(products.name, products.description, products.parameters) 
        AGAINST('intel core i5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ) AND percentage > 0 
ORDER BY percentage DESC;
```

This fulltext search query works well, when I don't use `percentage > 0`. It gives me error saying `#1054 - Unknown column 'percentage' in 'where clause'`. `percentage` is an alias, why I can't use it in the where condition?

Note: I'm using MariaDB 10.1.13

Comment: Wrap your query up in a derived table. Keep percentage condition on the outside.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Ok, nvermind, I found a solution with `HAVING percentage > 0`.

Comment: Just a note, that solution will only work with MySQL/mariadb.

Comment: I know, I use just these.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the percentage alias in your where clause because the where clause is computed before the select clause by SQL server. See this blog post for more information: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

Comment: Thanks for info, it will be handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to the issue:    Change `WHERE` to `HAVING`.